How to configure an Apache reverse proxy for GitLab with websocket?
I have a self-hosted GitLab instance behind an Apache reverse proxy.  Since one of the last releases, real-time updates stopped working.  One symptom I could detect was that some websocket calls (to wss://gitlab.example.com/-/cable) seem to fail with a 404:

This looks like a possible Apache config problem, so how can I configure my Apache reverse proxy to allow these connections?  The relevant part of my current setting looks like this:
ProxyRequests     off
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass        / https://0.0.0.0:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://0.0.0.0:4000/


What did the trick was to add a special rule for the websocket ressource, before the general proxy setting:
ProxyRequests     off
ProxyPreserveHost on

# The first matching rule wins
ProxyPass        /-/cable wss://0.0.0.0:4000/-/cable
ProxyPassReverse /-/cable wss://0.0.0.0:4000/-/cable

ProxyPass        / https://0.0.0.0:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://0.0.0.0:4000/

